# VB6 POS Printer - Logo register

Tags: vb6, printers, thermal-printer

Hy, I have a printer Star TSP100ECO [USB] and I made a program to print a ticket, but I should also add the logo on the ticket.
The problem is that I do not understand how to add a logo to the ticket with the help of ESC FS q.
Adding the logo using the printers configuration tool is not an option.
Registering the logo on page 3-98. -> http://www.starmicronics.com/support/Mannualfolder/linemode_cm_en.pdf
The picture that I wanted to print is in GIF format and is black and white.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Possibly no help at all, but can you use the Printer.PaintPicture method?

Comment: I rather use ESC FS q. If I use the Printer.PaintPicture then I had to disable the default option auto cutting. Because after Printer.PaintPicture printer cuts ticket, prints the text part and then again cuts.
Or is there a way to disable this option through VB6?

Answer (score 0):

Loading data can be done using the commands specified in the maual, but this will require a fair bit of picture decoding to preload the logo into the printer.

If paintpicture is working other than having to disable automatic cutting, then that will be the easiest way to go.

1) disable automatic cutting
2) print what you need from vb
3) printer.print chr(27) & chr(100) & chr(0)

Part 3 will perform the cut for you (in this case a full cut) partial cut can be used if you prefer by changing the 0 to another value according to the manual.

Comment: Changing default option on hundreds of computers that are already installed is a little bit tricky. Because of that i want to use ESC FS q. Or is there another way?

But thanks anyway.

Comment: So this is to upgrade an existing application, are you intending to register the logo in the printer before every print? as the logo is designed to be changed infrequently, with just a print command.  So in effect you will be changing default options on hundreds of printers anyway.  Star do however provide a full SDK for dealing with their printers, a readme for vb.net can be found here http://www.starmicronics.com/support/ZipFile.aspx?sat2=128 or for vb6 http://www.starmicronics.com/support/ZipFile.aspx?sat2=136,  hope that helps.

Comment: Yes i intend to register logo on every print. I wrote a program that modifies configuration xml of Stars Configuration program that is in C:\ProgramData\StarMicronics\TSP100\Configuration\SN XXXXXX\default config.xml. And it works on administrators account. But the problem was that program is running on windows with account that has limited premission and its not allowed to change this file. Is there a way to bypass this?